# DateTime custom format not as expected

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

I've been using custom formats for displaying DateTimes as found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

e.g.

```
new DateTime(2011,10,5).ToString("dd");
```

Returns: `"05"`

and:

```
new DateTime(2011,10,5).ToString("d MM");
```

Returns `"5 10"`

Which are both as I would expect, but:

```
new DateTime(2011,10,5).ToString("d");
```

Returns: `"05/10/2011"`

When I would have expected it to return: `"5"`

This doesn't matter in practise as you would use: `new DateTime(2011,10,5).Day` to get the day, but I am interested as to why the custom format didn't work as I would have expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try reading here [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) `"d" Short date pattern.`. Yes, it was probably a little stupid to reuse the `d` :-), fortunately it's a corner case.

In general you should always use the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, for things that aren't input/output to the user, unless you know EXACTLY what you are doing and you know your program won't be sold abroad. So if you are showing a date to the user, use his culture/the local culture. If you are asking a date to the user the same. But if you are using the date to name a file or to do some internal operations, normally it's better to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA")));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA")));

Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

and tell me what you see :-)

Comment: Well, *either* the invariant culture *or* a standard format which is expected to be valid for the user :)

Comment: @JonSkeet As you said, but for the "server" part I think using "local" years could be a little.... complex and ripe for bugs :-) (so if you have to name a file based on the current date, it's probably better to use the InvariantCulture)

Comment: For naming a file, I totally agree. But you did say "in general" :)

Answer (score 4):

As xanatos said, it's treating "d" as a standard date and time format string.

If you want a *custom* date and time format string of just "d", you need to effectively escape it to say "don't treat this as a standard pattern!"

```
new DateTime(2011, 10, 5).ToString("%d");
```

The `%` here is the "escape from standard to custom" part.

From the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers), sectino "using single custom format specifiers":

> A custom date and time format string consists of two or more characters. Date and time formatting methods interpret any single-character string as a standard date and time format string. If they do not recognize the character as a valid format specifier, they throw a FormatException. For example, a format string that consists only of the specifier "h" is interpreted as a standard date and time format string. However, in this particular case, an exception is thrown because there is no "h" standard date and time format specifier.
>
> To use any of the custom date and time format specifiers as the only specifier in a format string (that is, to use the "d", "f", "F", "g", "h", "H", "K", "m", "M", "s", "t", "y", "z", ":", or "/" custom format specifier by itself), include a space before or after the specifier, or include a percent ("%") format specifier before the single custom date and time specifier.
>
> For example, "%h" is interpreted as a custom date and time format string that displays the hour represented by the current date and time value. You can also use the " h" or "h " format string, although this includes a space in the result string along with the hour.

Comment: @xanatos: Have edited the answer with a link and a bit of the docs.